# How do I fix Postfix Submission TLS Error - unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:

Tags: postfix, tls

I have a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 install with mail system setup broadly as per:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu

and I get the following errors:

```
Jun  1 08:07:48 ocean postfix/submission/smtpd[21217]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308: 

Jun  1 08:07:51 ocean postfix/submission/smtpd[21222]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308: 

Jun  1 08:19:32 ocean postfix/submission/smtpd[21340]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308: 

Jun  1 08:41:54 ocean postfix/smtps/smtpd[22197]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:
```

185 of them in the last 24 hours and the system isn't live yet.

To pick one and give some more context:

```
Jun  1 08:52:58 ocean named[1814]: client @0x7fb35c3fe258 127.0.0.1#59947 (78.211.104.172.in-addr.arpa): query: 78.211.104.172.in-addr.arpa IN PTR +E(0) (127.0.0.1)
Jun  1 08:52:58 ocean named[1814]: client @0x7fb35c3fe258 127.0.0.1#59065 (cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net): query: cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net IN A +E(0) (127.0.0.1)
Jun  1 08:52:59 ocean postfix/smtpd[22291]: connect from cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net[172.104.211.78]
Jun  1 08:52:59 ocean postfix/smtpd[22291]: SSL_accept error from cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net[172.104.211.78]: -1
Jun  1 08:52:59 ocean postfix/smtpd[22291]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:
Jun  1 08:52:59 ocean postfix/smtpd[22291]: lost connection after STARTTLS from cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net[172.104.211.78]
Jun  1 08:52:59 ocean postfix/smtpd[22291]: disconnect from cloud-scanner-c5ca2208.internet-research-project.net[172.104.211.78] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 commands=1/2
```

Only reference on google I can find is a bug report, with very limited info here:

https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1854063.html

Any help or guidance appreciated.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Is being addressed here I believe: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix/+bug/1995312

Answer (score 1):

Remove parameter= from etc/default/saslauthd:

#PWDIR="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
#PARAMS="-m ${PWDIR}"
#PIDFILE="${PWDIR}/saslauthd.pid"

Make the file like /etc/default/saslauthd.dpkg-dist in 22.04.

See also  https://forum.virtualmin.com/t/sasl-authentication-failure-after-updating-20-04-to-ubuntu-22-04/116526/4

Comment: Unforunataly I do not have a /etc/default/saslauthd, infact I do not have saslauthd at all.

Comment: Indeed. Such a pity, I was hoping for something simple as the answer implied. In fact, while the answer might make sense if you have Webmin installed, a plain 22.04 install will not need `saslauthd`, if you have Postfix using the Dovecot SASL library (as opposed to the Cyrus SASL library).

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Postfix 3.7.4, released in Jan '23. The version on Ubuntu 22.04.2 is 3.6.4 (`postconf -d mail_version`). See [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg97759.html), or search `SSL_OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF` for the details.

This seems not to be a security issue, so the only downside is some extra syslog messages (I get about 5 a day).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar error, but it was related to the postfix message size limit.
I've postfix/dovecot/amavis/clamav running on ubuntu 22.04

**Problem**: Mail with large attachments

*Logfile: /var/log/syslog*

warning: TLS library problem: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:308:

*Logfile: /var/log/mail.err*

mail dovecot: auth: Error: auth client 0 disconnected with 1 pending requests: EOF

**Solution:**

1. check your limit by *"postconf | grep message_size_limit"*
2. Increase to 50MB by *"postconf -e message_size_limit=52428800"*

Comment: Thanks very much for the sugestion, but not my issue unfortunataly:  root@xxx:/home/xxx# postconf | grep message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 52428800